# Can Mathematica solve A Sin[t]^2 + B Cos[t]^2==1 for {A,B}?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Can Mathematica solve `A Sin[t]^2 + B Cos[t]^2==1 for {A,B}`?

The solution to the statement

```
ForAll[t,Exists[{A,B},A Sin[t]^2+B Cos[t]^2==1]]
```

is easily found through inspection as `A==B==1`, but `Resolve[]` of the statement does not find the solution.  Is there a way that Mathematica can solve this equation?

Answer (score 9):

```
Reduce[a Sin[t]^2 + b Cos[t]^2 == 1, {a, b, t}];
Cases[%, _[___, a == 1, ___, b == 1, ___]]
```

> {(-π + t)/(2 π) ∉ Integers && a == 1 && b == 1}

**Update**

Assuming $\{a,b\}\in\mathbb{R}$.

```
Reduce[a Sin[t]^2 + b Cos[t]^2 == 1 && a ∈ Reals && b ∈ Reals, {a, b, t}]
```

> (a == 1 && b == 1) || ((a | b) ∈ Reals && 
>      C[1] ∈ Integers && 
>      a - b != 
>       0 && (t == 1/2 (-ArcCos[(-2 + a + b)/(a - b)] + 2 π C[1]) || 
>        t == 1/2 (ArcCos[(-2 + a + b)/(a - b)] + 2 π C[1])))

```
Cases[%, _[___, a == 1, ___, b == 1, ___]]
```

> {a == 1 && b == 1}

Comment: What's the rest of the output?  It makes no sense that $t$ would have to be an odd multiple of $\pi$, which is what your first condition is saying;  the conditions still hold no matter what $t$ is. Pperhaps there are other conditions that were returned, other than the `Last`?

Comment: I assume you don't have access to M, or else you would evaluate it instead of asking? I can put it in, but they are somewhat bulky. The condition for all $t$ is obtained when we assume $a$ and $b$ are real.

Comment: I'm working from home and didn't want to go through the hassle of firing up my college's VPN to see what the full result was.  Mainly I just wanted to see whether there was some kind of bug in Mathematica's output, or whether it was just phrased in some arcane way.  In my experience, `Reduce` rarely outputs its results in the "nicest" possible way.

Answer (score 3):

"For all t " means

```
D[a Sin[t]^2 + b Cos[t]^2 - 1,t]==0//Simplify
(*(a - b) Sin[2 t] == 0=> a==b*)

a Sin[t]^2 + b Cos[t]^2 == 1 /.b->a//Simplify
(*a==1*)
```